# adding objects to NsMutableArray Depending on how many checkboxs are checked

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I have a contact list of people and right next to their name has a checkbox.

[1 http://i.minus.com/jyLvkUt7wnxYs.png](http://i.minus.com/jyLvkUt7wnxYs.png)

I want to store the cell text to an array when its selected, and when its unselected it removes it from the array. my code only works fine if 1 is selected, but when i select mulitple checkboxes, and when i log it, it only gives me 1 value. Here is my code below.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AddressBookViewController.h"

@class AddressBookViewController;

@interface AddressBookCell : UITableViewCell {
IBOutlet UIButton *checkbox;
NSMutableArray *array;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *checkbox;
@end
```

the .m file

```
#import "AddressBookCell.h"

@implementation AddressBookCell
@synthesize checkbox;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    self.checkbox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect checkboxRect = CGRectMake(135, 150, 36, 36);
    [self.checkbox setFrame:checkboxRect];  
    [self.checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected@2x.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.checkbox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.accessoryView = self.checkbox;
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}
return self;
```

}

```
-(void)checkboxClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
sender.selected = !sender.selected;
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview;
if(sender.selected){
    [array addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
}else{
    if([array containsObject:cell.textLabel.text]){
        [array removeObject:cell.textLabel.text];
        NSLog(@"it got removed");
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",array);
}


-(void)dealloc{
[super dealloc];
}
```

### EDIT

```
-(void)checkboxClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
sender.selected = !sender.selected;
UITableViewCell *cell = (AddressBookCell *)sender.superview;
if(sender.selected){
    [abController.savedPeople addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
}else{
    if([abController.savedPeople containsObject:cell]){
        [abController.savedPeople removeObject:cell];
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `NSMutableArray` is defined as part of your table cell, which means each cell has its own array, which is why you'll never have more than one item in this array. You need to declare this array as a member of your `UITableView` instead.

Comment: i get a breakpoint when i click the button?, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: just kidding, xcode was just being stupid, i just deleted the code and wrote it again and it worked.

Comment: it still did not add the cell to ab.controller.savedPeople

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your app is presenting the entire list each time and then performing a task with the selection. Is that right? You select/deselect people and then it stores them, and sends a text? Then you want to save the previous selection for the next time the user pulls up the contact selection?

In my opinion, you should use an `NSMutableSet` instead of an array for this task. It doesn't appear that order matters and a Set would be more appropriate.  I would declare a property for the set like `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet *contactList;` and then `@synthesize contactList;`

Then, when your user hits "done" or whatever they hit when they have made their selection you store the selected options in an NSSet. This NSSet is copied over to your NSMutableSet using `[self.contactList setSet:myNonMutableSet];`. Then every time you pull up the list you just check what was selected last time by calling `self.contactList` for the last state.

Comment: should i put the NSSet in my TableView Class, or tableViewController class?

Comment: It should be in your controller class (or whatever class you define as your datasource)